# Why setting tabbar item title and image in storyboard not working at times?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

When I tried to set the tabbar title and image on storyboard and ran the Simulator, for some reasons it doesn't display those titles and images and instead display the default `Item1`, `Item2`, etc... with no image. My another app can display it properly. Also, when I tried to set it from `AppDelegate.m`, it can display them properly. I can also set tintColor in `AppDelegate.m`.

So why is it not feasible to set it on storyboard sometimes? I set both titles and images as well as tags correctly. I don't know any reasons why it doesn't work...

Isn't it enough to set it on the tabbar of the the top view controller of the navigation controller, right? Or is there something that has to be set other than the setting on the storyboard, such as say, build settings? What am I missing?

Or should I set it only from within code? I use Xcode 5.1.

Comment: Put the screenshot of your storyboard. Somewhere something small is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Self Answer

I tried to delete the storyboard file and then created it again, and filled those titles as well as images (and other UI components that was there), it displayed them properly for some reasons. I don't know why the original storyboard file was not working at all - the only difference is that I created localized storyboard files before setting those images and titles, but of course I did set them after that in every localized file but it wasn't still working...